# Смысл верстки через списки ul > li (html / css)?

Tags: html, css

Интересует несколько вопросов по теме "почему и когда использовать списки"?

1. Возьмем за основу простое меню, для чего здесь нужны li список, если можно обойтись `div > a`, получается структура на 1 уровень менее вложенная. Может здесь есть какой-то более глубокий смысл?

```html
<ul class="nav">
<li class="nav__item item">
<a class="item__link">Пункт меню</a>
</li>
<li class="nav__item item">
<a class="item__link">Пункт меню</a>
</li>
<li class="nav__item item">
<a class="item__link">Пункт меню</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

```html
<div class="nav">
<a class="nav__item">Пункт меню</a>
<a class="nav__item">Пункт меню</a>
<a class="nav__item">Пункт меню</a>
</div>
```

2. Допустим, что списки использовать нужно и для этого нашли разумный довод, тогда следующий вопрос. Например есть шапка из 3х блоков: логотип, блок с контактами 1, блок с контактами 2. Здесь тоже использовать `ul.header > li.logo, li.contacts-1, li.contacts-2`? Разве не будет разумно использовать `div.header (или просто header) > div.logo, div.contacts-1, div.contacts-2`?

Comment: Краткое содержание ответов: потому что семантика.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> для чего здесь нужны li список, если можно обойтись `div > a`, получается структура на 1 уровень менее вложенная.

Во-первых, поисковые системы поймут, что это не простой текст, и в поисковой выдаче не будет мешанины вроде `текст до меню Пункт менюПункт менюПункт меню текст после меню`.

Во-вторых, разметка списком окажет большую услугу пользователям экранных дикторов, так как в этом случае каждый пункт меню словесно отделяется (что очень важно при отсутствии какой-либо пунктуации между вашими `<a>`).

В-третьих, ваше меню будет адекватно отображаться даже при сбое в загрузке CSS-стилей, либо полном отсутствии их поддержки (текстовые браузеры по типу lynx достаточно популярны до сих пор).

Comment: Полезная информация(+)

Comment: @Arhad согласен с Артуром, что полезная информация, но ведь кто-то минуснул. Ставлю плюс для компенсации (+)